# can Changing the workspace complaince to JRE 1.7 have an effect on my code compability?

Tags: android, java

Im developing an android app was about to use a switch with string argument, i am making sure it is ok to let the compiler do as it suggested and change whatever needs to be changed, by ok i mean wont effect the runnability of my app...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch-on-string thing is only syntax sugar, so it should result in byte code that is convertible to DEX. That said, the Android VM (Dalvik) only knows about Java 6, so it would be best if you stick with it.

Comment: ok thanks, i will stick to that.